# Understanding Gap Events and Transaction Key Handling

Tags: change-data-capture, gap-events

Consider a scenario where a transaction with the key "00000a82-7f3f-1c17-2bd3-7c636bd96311" is initiated. The transaction involves creating a case followed by creating an email message. Salesforce commits changes and begins sending CDC(Change Data Capture) events. But what happens if an internal error occurs while sending a CDC for the email message? Salesforce will send a gap create event for this change, raising two key questions:

1. Will the gap event also have the same transaction key "00000a82-7f3f-1c17-2bd3-7c636bd96311," or will it be assigned a different transaction key?
2. Will the order of the change events be maintained, meaning the first CDC event will be the create event for the case followed by the gap event for the email message, or can these events be disordered?

Comment: Reading the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_replication_steps.htm) suggests that the gap event would have the same transaction ID (see point 3.a in the high level outline). That same documentation suggests you ignore change events until reconciliation is done.

Comment: Hi, There's nothing related to the question posted :(.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_replication_steps.htm) you see:

> A transaction-based replication process involves these high-level steps.
>
> 1. In your subscribed client, allocate a transaction buffer for each transaction key. For example, create a map (Map<String, List>) where the key is the transactionKey value.
> 2. Open a subscription to the general /data/ChangeEvents channel that captures all enabled events.
> 3. For each change event received over the channel, check the changeType field.
>
>    1. If the changeType field is GAP_CREATE, GAP_UPDATE, GAP_DELETE, or GAP_UNDELETE, the event is a gap event. Follow the recommended steps in How to Handle a Gap Event.
>    2. If the changeType field is GAP_OVERFLOW, the event is an overflow event.
>
>       1. Process the change events that you previously stored in the map. Commit the changes, and then purge the corresponding map entry.
>       2. For the overflow event, follow the recommended steps in How to Handle an Overflow Event.
> 4. If the event isn’t a gap or overflow event, it’s a change event. Deserialize the change event, and add it to the appropriate map entry for the transaction key.
> 5. When the transactionKey value changes in the next change event, commit the changes in the map entry for the previous transaction key, and then purge the map entry.
> 6. Repeat steps 3 through 5 for each new event received.

Looking at the point that there are transaction buffers based on the transaction key, and that step 3 covers gap and overflow events with step 5 handling the rest, I think it is pretty clear that the answer to your first question is that the gap event has the same transaction key as the related events, assuming the email sending is part of the same transaction as the updates to the record.

The documentation also covers the fact that when you see a gap event, you should switch to a mode where you ignore all (subsequent) change events for the same transaction and once that transaction sequence is complete you should react appropriately (e.g. explicitly fetching all details for the record):

> If you receive change events for new changes for the same record before the data has been reconciled, don't process them.

It doesn't specifically explain sequencing, so no direct answer to your second point, I expect that the events would maintain order (since they simply go into a queue and there's nothing to suggest the queue order would be changed simply because there's a different type of event added). It does explicitly cover that you should deal with gaps in a specific way.